# How to change the button text from show to hide after click, and also keep it showen after slide up?

Tags: java, jquery, slidetoggle

i'm trying to do something similler to the map you can see at the end of this site,
http://www.insegment.com/

Here's the html

```
    <div class="clear">
    <button id=slideToggle>Show full map</button>
<div class="slideTogglebox">            
</div> </div>
```

Script:

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {   $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle(500); });
```

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do...

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {   

$(this).html(($(this).html()=="Show full map"?"Hide map":"Show full map"));

// To move up
$(this).toggleClass("moveUp");

$('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle(500); 

});
```

And put the `css` to move up in `moveUp`

Comment: Thank you that's really helpfull, but also i need to make the button slide up with the div and keep visible, any idea?

Comment: Did you see the example? i need to move the botton up and keep it visible, cuz when i place it into "slideTogglebox" div it's just hide complatly.

Comment: See the updated answer.  For more query please post different thread. If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: Did it worked? Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct.

Comment: You can mark it as correct answer. It helps others to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7ybcw1n/1/),

Also.... you're missing a `</div>`